# Calculate with Values in Union Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, unpivot

In SQL Server, I am looking for the best way to reuse values within a union select to use them within calculations:

Like:

```
---------------------
select max(value) as V1
from table

union

select min(value) as V2
from table

union

select V1 + V2 as V3
from table
```

The only way I know is with declare like:

```
---------------------
declare @V1 as int
declare @V2 as int

select
@V1 = max(value)
@V2 = min(value)
from table

select @V1
union
select @V2
union
select @V1 + @V2
```

this works but isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver? Also, clarify whether you have two tables (as in the first code snippet), or just one (as in the second code block).

Comment: There is a logical difference between union and union all. If your min and max values are the same, you will get 2 rows rather than 3. Yes - a very rare probability but the sorting and duplicate removal only makes the query less efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CTE that returns the min and max:

```
with cte as (select min(value) min_value, max(value) max_value from tablename)
select min_value from cte
union
select max_value from cte
union
select min_value + max_value from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, I would recommend `cross apply` to unpivot the columns to rows:

```
select x.v
from (select min(value) v1, max(value) v2 from mytable) t
cross apply (values (t.v1), (t.v2), (t.v1 + t.v2)) x(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use STRING_SPLIT because it is better than pivot

```
declare @a as varchar
select @a=cast(min(value) as varchar)+','+cast(min(value)+max(value) as varchar)+','+cast(max(value) as varchar) 
from tablename

SELECT value
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@a, ',' )
```